# unable to import rest_framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have Anaconda installed in my system but clearly I have set up a new and clean environment for a **django API** project. I also have all the necessary requirements installed for the **API**. But when I try to import **rest_framework** it gives me an error saying **"Unable to import 'rest_framework' "** even when I have done the following:

```
#settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'api',
]

#serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers #<---- this line is giving me error
from .models import Plans   
    class PlansSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer to map the Model instance into JSON format."""
class Meta: 
    """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
    model = Plans
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'date_created', 'date_modified')
    read_only_fields = ('date_created', 'date_modified')
```

**requirements.txt**

```
certifi==2018.11.29
Django==2.1.7
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-filter==2.1.0
django-markdown==0.8.4
django-markdown2==0.3.1
django-pagedown==1.0.6
djangorestframework==3.9.2
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.1.0
Markdown==3.0.1
markdown2==2.3.7
olefile==0.46
Pillow==5.4.1
Pygments==2.3.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2018.9
```

> I also always deactivate the conda's **base** environment and only activate the required environment.

Comment: check your editor's python environment.

Comment: Try making a new virtual environment and then doing a `pip install djangorestframework` just to see if it's an environment issue?

Comment: I don't there is any issue in the virtual environment @Reez0 . Because the **requirements.txt** includes the **djangrestframework**, which means I already have the package.